# Run "mvn site" with checkstyle and a custom checkstyle.xml through command line?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I want to run

```
mvn site
```

and have it include checkstyle, with a checkstyle.xml specified on the command line.

One can do

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.config.location=/path/to/checkstyle.xml
```

But I want the "site" output as well.

Reason: I have multiple projects where I basically want to do this, but I can't (or don't want to) modify pom.xml and add/edit checkstyle.xml in each one.

Answer (score 0):

If those projects share a common parent pom the `pluginManagement` section of the parent pom would be a good place to add your settings:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <configLocation>/path/to/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

If this is not the case for you, you may try using a master pom which uses the projects in question as sub-modules. This might be to cumbersome to be of real use though.